# “Thought is a thread, and the raconteur is a spinner of yarns"

Tags: meaning, etymology, metaphors, archaicisms

> “Thought is a thread, and the raconteur is a spinner of yarns"

What does this metaphor mean and what is the origin? I know it is an ancient one, but couldn't find anything else! Is it obsolete now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To ***spin a yarn*** is an idiom/metaphor for telling a long tale. From [Etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=text&allowed_in_frame=0) [bold is mine]:

> **text (n.)** 
>   late 14c., “wording of anything written,” from Old French texte, Old North French *tixte* (12c.), from Medieval Latin *textus* “the Scriptures, text, treatise,” in Late Latin “written account, content, characters used in a document,” from Latin *textus* “style or texture of a work,” literally **“thing woven,”** from past participle stem of **texere** ***“to weave,”*** from PIE root **tek-* “to weave, to fabricate, to make; make wicker or wattle framework” (see ***texture***).
>
> > An ancient metaphor: ***thought is a thread, and the raconteur is a spinner of yarns — but the true storyteller, the poet, is a weaver.*** The scribes made this old and audible abstraction into a new and visible fact. After long practice, their work took on such an even, flexible texture that they called the written page a *textus*, which means cloth. [Robert Bringhurst, *The Elements of Typographic Style*]

So it is a play on words.

If thought can be seen as a thread of conciousness, then the story-teller is spinning long threads together into yarn, which is spun thread.

[image]
<sub>(source: [interweave.com](http://eimages.interweave.com/freemiums/SpinningDaily/types-of-yarn/hand-spinning-yarn2.jpg))</sub>

Robert Bringhurst then continues to use yarn as a metaphor which is woven into a poem.

Comment: I love the Bringhurst reference. The extended sense of *yarn* has only been with us for the past 200 years, when *spinning a yarn* first began to take on its metaphorical meaning: “to tell a story (usually a long one); also, ‘to pitch a tale’. Hence *yarn* = a (long) story or tale: sometimes implying one of a marvellous or incredible kind; also, a mere tale. *colloq.”* [OED]

Comment: The English verb *weave* is a strong one, so it’s *is woven* not *is *weaved*; see Dutch *weven* and German *weben*. FTR OED has for *weave*: “to form or fabricate (a stuff or material) by interlacing yarns or other filaments of a particular substance in a continuous web; to manufacture in a loom by crossing the threads or yarns called respectively the warp and the weft.” Space-age looms have a warp drive. :) Also, Bringhurstto’s name has a typo.

Comment: Aha. The name was copied from etymonline - thanks for the edits

Comment: Do we have a substitute for this idiom now?

Comment: There are synonyms, but spinning a yarn is very much used today still. synonyms: story, tale, anecdote, saga, narrative; tall tale, tall story, fish story, cock-and-bull story, shaggy-dog story, spiel
"a far-fetched yarn"

Answer (score 4):

Weaving and storytelling (and lying) have been associated as far back
as anyone can trace in Indo-European cultures:

[P.I.E. ****teks***](http://web.archive.org/web/20080627024024/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE523.html)- Source of: *textile text tissue context pretext subtle architect technical,* among others

- To weave; also to fabricate, especially with an ax; also to make wicker or wattle
  fabric for (mud-covered) house walls. *text, tissue; context, pretext,*
  from Latin *texere*, to weave, fabricate.
- Suffixed form **teks-la*. *tiller*[2](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628053511/http://www.bartleby.com/61/IEroots.html), *toil*[2](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628053511/http://www.bartleby.com/61/IEroots.html), from Latin *tela*, web, net, warp of a fabric, also weaver's beam (to which the warp threads are tied);
- Prefixed form *subtle*, from Latin *subtilis*, thin, fine, precise, subtle (< **sub-tela*, "thread passing under the warp,'' the finest thread; *sub*, under; see **hupo*-).
- Suffixed form **teks-on*, weaver, maker of wattle for house walls, builder, akin to
  **teks-tor*, builder; *tectonic, architect*, fr. Gk τέκτων (tektōn), carpenter, builder.
- Suffixed form **teks-na-*, craft (of weaving or fabricating). *technical, polytechnic,
  technology*, fr. Gk τέχνη (tekhnē) ‘art, craft, skill’.
  (Source: [Watkins (2000)](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628053511/http://www.bartleby.com/61/IEroots.html), Pokorny (1959) *tekt*- 1058.*teks-*)

The metaphor is obvious; you tell a story like you make clothing. Repetition and pattern, moving the story along a path like a piece of thread you're spinning, putting large pieces together, crafting small pieces carefully, to get things put together right. It's art and it's craft and it's a valuable skill. Especially in a non-literate society.

So the metaphor theme **Storytelling Is Weaving**
as well as the fact that storytelling is lying
licenses these instantiations

- *loom of language, weave a story/spell, thread of discourse, warp and woof*

including these, where the textile metaphor has an association of telling lies:

- *fabricating evidence, spin a yarn, tissue of lies, pull the wool over X’s eyes, out of whole cloth*

> from http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LanguageFossils.pdf

Comment: Didn’t know that about *subtle* having an origin that involved *tela*, a word I always remember because of modern Spanish *telaraña*: spiderweb.

Comment: Great answer. I knew about *tela*, but I had no idea the others were related. Now I wonder whether Greek *tattô* "order" might be related. Pokórny remains silent; Chaintraine doesn't know; Hofmann suggests a root **tā̌g-*, presumably meaning "could be short or long" (I can't find a better way to type a combination of breve and macron).

Comment: Proto-Nostratic has only one word. All the rest are derived.

Comment: The Morphological Big Bang.